# Conditional statement for meta <title> </title> using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I make a conditional statement in meta title?

```
<title> if (home page)
{
    ...
}
else (post title)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. How does a IF not work? Or how about just echo $title ?

Comment: To all: What is meant by "meta"? Is it a CodeIgniter thing?

Answer (score 3):

It's better to transfer the title from the controller in a variable to the view. You can echo the variable on the view.

In the controller

```
$data['title'] = "Your page title";

$this->load->view('result_view', $data);
```

In your view (file *result_view.php*)

```
<html>
.
.
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
.
.
.
.
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<title><?=($this->uri->segment(1) == '') ? 'homepage' : 'subpage';?></title>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: What is the idea? Using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)?